# Commanding Maxon Motors EPOS2 Motor Controller from MATLAB

Tags: c, matlab, eval, mex, mingw-w64

I want to communicate with `EPOS2 Maxon Driver`. Here is what I found on [File Exchange](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/53735-commanding-maxon-motors-epos2-motor-controller-from-matlab#functions_tab) to do it.

- Download [the link](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/f21110f4-7a68-436f-a525-8ca22d5a586b/2f0560c9-96ba-43b6-a805-bf98cf926751/packages/zip) and create `Epos2Windows` as a empty folder in `\Version2` where  `Make.m` exist.
- Add [MinGW-w64](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/52848-matlab-support-for-mingw-w64-c-c-compiler) to`Matlab`.
- Install [EPOS2 USB driver](http://www.maxonmotor.com/medias/sys_master/root/8811482415134/EPOS-USB-Driver-Installation-En.zip) .
- Download [EPOS-Windows-DLL-En](http://www.maxonmotor.com/medias/sys_master/root/8815100133406/EPOS-Windows-DLL-En.zip).
- copy `Definitions.h`, `EposCmd.lib`, `EposCmd64.lib`, `vxlapi.dll`, `vxlapi64.dll` from `\EPOS-Windows-DLL-En\Microsoft Visual C++\Definition Files` to `Epos2Windows`folder.

Finally when I use `Make` command, there are lots of errors starting with `Error using mex and ...`

I started to find out what the problem is. So I ran `Make.m` code line by line. I found the problem in `eval( char(strcmd) )`. Now I have no idea to handle it.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: errors1]
[image: errors2]

Win10, MATLAB R2017b

Comment: Can you please show the actual error message regarding `eval(...)` in your question?

Comment: @SvenKrüger there are a ton of errors I just put first and last page of it. if u run 'Make' code line by line base on what u want is better.

Comment: These error messages tell you that there is something wrong with the C code. You might need to have a look into those sources... Can you please show the value of `strcmd`, before it is executed? Maybe there is an include missing.

Comment: @SvenKrüger this is the strcmd for first iteration of code: `strcmd = strcat('mex', sourcecode(:,i), ' -D', definitions, ' -I',  includedir, ' -L', includedir, ' -l', libeposname);`

Comment: If you delete the semicolon at the end of this line, what is printed out on the MATLAB console?

Comment: @SvenKrüger  `1×25 cell array` with a lot of varname in it this is why I wrote that. sorry for taking your time but I suggest you to install it, maybe its not only `matlab` problem.

Comment: I am compiling my MEX-Files using Visual Studio Professional. You do not need to have a key for VS you only need to install it. Maybe you should try it with VS, but pay attention to [compatibility](https://uk.mathworks.com/content/dam/mathworks/mathworks-dot-com/support/sysreq/files/SystemRequirements-Release2017b_SupportedCompilers.pdf).

Comment: The first error generated by the compiler indicates that the code is written for a C++ computer, but is being compiled by a C compiler.

Comment: @CrisLuengo  I changed my compiler `mex -setup cpp` and run it again but it didn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way that I solved the problem in `Win10_LTSC, Matlab_2019a`:
Install `MinGW64 Compiler with Windows 10 SDK or later (C++)` for `Mex` of `Matlab`.
there are some commands in the files that need to be compiled by the `cpp compiler`. `mex` changes it compiler as see filetype so change all of 25 files with type `.c` to `.cpp` in the [image: folder] and [image: Make.m].

to avoid the error of `invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'real_T*`, change `real_T       *y = ssGetOutputPortSignal(S,0);` [line 274 in sfun_maxon.cpp] to `real_T       *y = (real_T *)ssGetOutputPortSignal(S,0);`.

open `test_epos.m` and set the true value of NodeId then run the code.